# Where to put the purge.php file in varnish server?

Tags: varnish

I am using two application load balancers that are routing requests to 4 backend varnish servers. I got answers to configure the PHP file to purge the cache but I have no idea where to put it and how to execute.

Answer (score 1):

For which type of PHP application are you trying to configure cache purging?

- A custom application?
- WordPress?
- Drupal?
- Magento?
- Some other CMS or framework?

If you're using an existing platform, CMS, or framework, the documentation will probably state how to configure purging.

### Varnish Configuration

Of course, the Varnish *VCL code* should also be tuned to process purges.

You can find more information about purging (and banning) in Varnish on http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/purging.html

Here are the questions you should ask yourself regarding purging. Maybe the documentation of your CMS or framework will answer these as well?

- Are you trying to purge individual URLs?
- Does your code have pattern matching in play to invalidate multiple URLs at once *(uses bans in VCL)*
- If pattern matching is used, are you sending the invalidation pattern via an HTTP request header?
- Does your invalidation code use the URL to identify objects in cache, or does it rely on tagged content?
- Are you restricting access to the purging mechanism based on IP address or subnet. If so, please configure an ACL in VCL.

> Many WordPress plugins rely on individual URL purging. Other WordPress plugins use bans through request header patterns.
>
> Drupal uses bans, but has a system in place that tags content. The ban patterns don't match URLs, but tags.
>
> Magento uses bans.

### Conclusion

If you use a CMS or framework, the purging strategy is set in advance. It's just a matter of configuring your app and making sure the VCL can handle it.

If you have custom code, you have a choice, and you can implement purging or banning.

> Please have a look at [the user guide section about purging](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/purging.html) I mentioned above. It should help you understand the underlying mechanism.